# SSH timeout for Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, ssh

After resizing my VM I am unable to SSH to my Linux Azure VM(Ubuntu 14.10).

I have already tried -

```
Resizing the VM

Resetting the password using new azure portal

Basically all the steps that are mentioned here :
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-ssh-connections/

Still I am getting "ssh: connect to host bookmarks.cloudapp.net port 22: Connection timed out"

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but we often come across this and want to add some solutions.

1. Check if Port 22 is Enabled/Allow on "default-allow-ssh" under "Inbound Port Rules". (Path: Dashboard > Select your VM > Networking (under Settings section)

   [image]
2. Logout of the Azure portal, clear browser cache and re-login

Answer (score 0):

If your VM is hosted in Southeast Asia, then you'll be affected by the issues they're currently having.

> VIRTUAL MACHINES customers will be unable to connect to their resources.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current

Comment: But I am having this issue from past 4 days. I tried everything before posting my question here. Though, VM is in East Asia not Southeast Asia.